# how show a box in form with a loop

Tags: loops, vue.js

hello i want to do a loop in my vuejs project something like this

```
<v-select
 v-model="create_event.nb_coach"
 :items="nb_coach"
 label="number Coach"
></v-select>
```

I select a number then I want to display this box below in relation to the number selected above. i think my seconde v-select need an array v-model ?

```
<v-select
 v-model="create_event.name_coach"
 :items="coach"
 item-text="name"
 label="name Coach"
></v-select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
<v-select
 v-for="(item, index) in create_event.nb_coach"
 v-bind:key="index"
 v-model="create_event.name_coach"
 :items="coach"
 item-text="name"
 label="name Coach"
></v-select>
```